# How to get SMART information on local disks in ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

How to get SMART information about local disks (no SmartArray) installed in ESXi host? It is HP DL G6 server, but without the HP Insight Suite.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [your earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/380175/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-sw-raid-in-vmware-esxi-vm/380177#380177), you are not using a standard Smart Array RAID controller. The device you have is a rebranded [LSI SAS3442E-R controller](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS3442E-R.aspx). It's meant to be a SAS HBA, and not a hardware RAID controller in this context.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was not clear enough, but I am not speaking about any HBAs or controllers, but "local" disks, that are attached to the internal SATA controller of the server.

Comment: The internal SATA controller in your system is an HBA. It's not a proper RAID controller, so ESXi doesn't quite support the way you're using it.